# placing items in span columns position (left,right,right) in PHP/XML

Tags: php, html

I have an XML file containing 15 items.
What I'm trying to do is to layout these items in a 3 span div.
where the first item is aligned left, and two consecutive items are aligned right.

here is the website in question. 
http://phantom-3.com/leoshop-pack/index.php

I'm referring to the 3 row of items.

I'm not sure how to loop through this so that the output is as expected. 
1 item "left" followed by 2 items "right".

Can someone please help me with this logic?

The problem is im using a template built by someone else which is meant to be responsive. I don't want to break the code by fiddling with it as im not that advanced with css. Is there any logic i can pass in php for the code to loop every 3 items. so I can construct the first row (item1:left,item2:right,item3:right) and pick back up at item4 for next loop reapting upto 15 items... ?

Thank you

Comment: Create a div with `width:100%` (or any value of your choice). Loop through it and give inner divs `width:33%;float:left` and under each div you put the elements of your choice

Comment: With CSS look up a the nth child selector such as div:nth-child(3n+3) {}, div:nth-child(2n+2) {} - This will help, also check out a previous answer in php loop `($i % 3) == 0`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806582/php-while-loop-variable-for-every-third-div

Comment: The problem is im using a template built by someone else which is meant to be responsive. I don't want to break the code by fiddling with it as im not that advanced with css. Is there any logic i can pass in php for the code to loop every 3 items. so I can construct the first row (item1:left,item2:right,item3:right) and pick back up at item4 for next loop reapting upto 15 items... ?

Comment: Thanks for the provided link.. from a quick glance, i think its in the right path.

Comment: if (($i % 3) == 0) At this position you know you are at a 3rd item. & your welcome