# PHP get every third item of list

Tags: php

I have used this code to toggle between classes for odd/even elements:

```
<li class="<?php echo ($key%2) ? "odd" : "even";>
```

How can I get every 3rd item, to add ex. classes 'one', 'two, 'three'?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806582/php-while-loop-variable-for-every-third-div

Look here,i think this might help you

Comment: I recommend you split the code from the presentation: e.g. set `$class` and then later do `<li class="$class">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's tough in a one-liner, but you could use a switch:
`<?php switch($key%3): case 0: echo "one"; break; case 1: echo "two"; break; case 2: echo "three"; break; ?>`

To clean up your HTML files, you could put this switch statement into a function.

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways. Here is a "oneliner":

```
<li class="<?php $t=$key%3; echo ($t==0?"one":$t==1?"two":"three");>
```

If you get more than 3 items you might get more manageable code with a switch statement:

```
<?php

switch($key%4){
case(0): echo "one"; break;
case(1): echo "two"; break;
case(2): echo "three"; break;
case(3): echo "four"; break;
}

?>
```

Comment: Elegant, just what I was looking for, but was going in a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you got your counter in your loop simple use modulo and check if it's 0. Then you can add the specific class.

```
if ($i % 3 == 0) { }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$classes = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

for (..) {
    printf('<li class="%s">', $classes[$key % count($classes)]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$classes = array('first','second','third');
for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {
    echo $i.' class: ' .current($classes);    
    if(!next($classes))
    {
        // reset if there is end of array
        reset($classes);
    }    
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

elastic solution, You can have 3,4,5... classes by modifing $classes array only.
Also is fast, don`t need to divide large numbers, just iterate small array with class listed in correct odrder

Answer (score 0):

If you want clean HTML, define a function like below,

It will apply `default` class to every element, `even` class to every second element and `third` class to every third element, you can extend it as you like,

```
function apply_class($i)
{
    $every = 'default';
    $every_second = 'even';
    $every_third = 'third';

    $return [] = 'default';
    if ( $i%2 == 0 ) { $return [] = $every_second; }
    if ( $i%3 == 0 ) { $return [] = $every_third; }

    return implode(' ', $return);
}
```

Use it like,

```
<li class="<?php echo apply_class($i)?>" > </li>
```

Will render HTML like,

```
$i

1   <li class="default"> </li>
2   <li class="default even"> </li>
3   <li class="default third"> </li>
4   <li class="default even"> </li>
5   <li class="default"> </li>
6   <li class="default even third"> </li>
7   <li class="default"> </li>
8   <li class="default even"> </li>
9   <li class="default third"> </li>
10  <li class="default even"> </li>
```