# Extract four records at a time from a database with php and bootstrap

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, twitter-bootstrap

I have a database, i need to extract from them four record at a time.

To extract all the records i use this query:

```
SELECT image FROM song ORDER BY date DESC
```

but i need to process 4 record at a time, because in HTML i close a row every 4 images.

```
echo"<div class='row'>";
while ($dati=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{
    echo"<a href='song.php'>";
    echo"<div class='col-md-3'>";
    echo"<img class='img-responsive' src='".$dati['immagine']."'><br>";
    echo"</div>";
    echo"</a>";
}
echo "</div><br>";
```

I need to re-execute the command above every 4 image record as long as there are records not processed in the database.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [php while loop variable for every third div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806582/php-while-loop-variable-for-every-third-div)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Module of 4 and display your format

```
<?php
$counter=0;
$str="";
while ($dati=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($counter%4==0)
    {
        $str="<div class='row'>";
    }

    $str.="<a href='song.php'>";
    $str.="<div class='col-md-3'>";
    $str.="<img class='img-responsive' src='".$dati['immagine']."'><br>";
    $str.="</div>";
    $str.="</a>";

    if($counter%4==0)
    {
         $str.="</div><br>";
    }


    $counter++;
}

echo  $str;
?>
```

or if you dont want store into string directly print like this

```
<?php
$counter=0;

while ($dati=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    if($counter%4==0)
    {
        echo "<div class='row'>";
    }

    echo "<a href='song.php'>";
    echo "<div class='col-md-3'>";
    echo "<img class='img-responsive' src='".$dati['immagine']."'><br>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</a>";

    if($counter%4==0)
    {
         echo "</div><br>";
    }


    $counter++;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`LIMIT 4` but I would recommand you to query the record once and to add a counter in your loop to know when you have a new row

Answer (score 0):

Use this query

```
SELECT image FROM song ORDER BY date DESC limit 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This will display four images in every row in your html using bootstrap after executing `SELECT image FROM song ORDER BY date DESC` .

```
$num_rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
for ($j = 0; $j < $num_rows; ++$j) 
      $dati[$j] = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);   //$dati is now a multidimensional array with an indexed array of rows, each containing an associative array of the columns

// You could alternatively use a for loop
// for($i=0; $i<$num_rows; $i++) insert while loop
$i=0;
while($i<$num_rows){ // start the loop to insert images in every row, 4 images per row
  echo"<div class='row'>";
  echo"<a href='song.php'>";
  echo"<div class='col-md-3'>";
  if($i<num_rows)   // this prevents excessive rows from being displayed after $i reaches the number of rows
    echo"<img class='img-responsive' src='".$dati[$i++]['immagine']."'><br>";   //post-increment $i
  if($i<num_rows)
    echo"<img class='img-responsive' src='".$dati[$i++]['immagine']."'><br>";
  if($i<num_rows)
    echo"<img class='img-responsive' src='".$dati[$i++]['immagine']."'><br>";
  if($i<num_rows)
    echo"<img class='img-responsive' src='".$dati[$i++]['immagine']."'><br>";
  echo"</div>";
  echo"</a>";
  echo "</div><br>"
}
```