# How to set the checkbox uncheck automatically when its reach 3rd checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, checkbox

I have many checkbox that comes from database and then using foreach loop. i put if else in my foreach loop to set if the user already select the 3rd checkbox then all other checkbox will reject the user selection like uncheck automatically or disabled. I want to make it disabled but if i do that all checkbox will be disabled. If you see the where i use if else condition for $countses, then there is where i want to use the code. but i don't how to make it uncheck automatically once the user has select the 3rd checkbox.

NOTE:i can disabled it by PHP.but it needs to be refreshed first rather than implement it directly. so i guess i need help in javascript

My code looks like this

```
$query="SELECT abc.*
            FROM (".$selector.")abc
            WHERE 
                abc.studentname LIKE :q OR
                abc.matricno LIKE :q OR
                abc.title LIKE :q OR
                abc.year LIKE :q OR
                abc.thesis_level LIKE :q OR
                abc.programme LIKE :q OR
                abc.serialno LIKE :q
            LIMIT ".$startrow.",".$limitrow;



$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':q','%'.$q.'%');
$stmt->bindValue(':e',$e);
$stmt->execute();


$startPage = ($pageno <5) ? 1 : $pageno -4;
$endPage = 8 + $startPage;
$endPage = ($maxpage < $endPage) ? $maxpage : $endPage;
$diff = $startPage - $endPage + 8;
$startPage -=($startPage - $diff > 0) ? $diff : 0;

$a = $startPage;

echo "<ol id='olpoint'>";

if($startPage > 1) echo "<a href='#' onclick='ajaxSearchUpdater(1);'><li>First</li></a>";

while($a<=$endPage){

        echo "<a href='#' onclick='ajaxSearchUpdater(".$a.");' style='text-decoration:none;'><li ";
        if($pageno == $a){
            echo "style='color:grey;font-size:medium;'";
        }
        echo ">".$a."</li></a>";
        $a++;
};

if($endPage < $maxpage) echo "<a href='#' onclick='ajaxSearchUpdater(".$maxpage.");'><li>End</li></a>";

echo "</ol>";





if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
    $r=$stmt->fetchAll();
    echo "<table class='tablesorter-blackice' id='myTable' style='width:97%; table-border: 1'>";
    echo "<thead>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>No.</th>";
    echo "<th>No.Matric</th>";
    echo "<th>Name</th>";
    echo "<th>Programme</th>";
    echo "<th>Title</th>";
    echo "<th>Thesis Level</th>";
    echo "<th>Serial Number</th>";
    echo "<th>Availability</th>";
    echo "<th>Select book (Max 3)</th>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</thead>";
    echo "<tbody>";

    if(isset($_SESSION['sBorrow']))
        $arraynosiri = $_SESSION['sBorrow'];
    else
        $arraynosiri = array();

    $countses = count($_SESSION['sBorrow']);

    foreach($r as $row){

            echo "<tr align='center'><td>". ($startrow+1) ."</td><td>". $row['matricno'] ."</td><td>". $row['studentname'] ."</td><td>". $row['programme'] ."</td><td>". $row['title'] ."</td><td>". $row['thesis_level'] ."</td><td>". $row['serialno'] ."</td><td>". $row['bavailable'] ."</td><td>
            <form method='post'>";
            if($key = array_search($row['serialno'], $arraynosiri) !== false) {
                $checkbox = "checked";
            }
            else{
                $checkbox = "";
            }


            if($countses > 3){
                echo "MAX";
            }
            else{
                echo "MIN";
            }


            if($row['bavailable'] == "Available"){
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sBorrow' id='sBorrow' class='sBorrow' value='". $row['serialno'] ."' ".$checkbox.">
                </form></td></tr>";
                }
                else{
                echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sBorrow' id='sBorrow' class='sBorrow' value='". $row['serialno'] ."' ".$checkbox." style='color: grey;' disabled>
                </form></td></tr>";
            }


            $startrow++;
            //echo $row['education_level'];


    }
    echo "</tbody>";
    echo "</table>";
}
else{
    echo "<p align='center' style='color:white'; class='reminder'>Nothing to show you :( I am really sorry for this T_T </p>";
}
```

**EDIT**

By using spring code, should i do it like this?
` foreach($r as $row){

```
        echo "<tr align='center'><td>". ($startrow+1) ."</td><td>". $row['matricno'] ."</td><td>". $row['studentname'] ."</td><td>". $row['programme'] ."</td><td>". $row['title'] ."</td><td>". $row['thesis_level'] ."</td><td>". $row['serialno'] ."</td><td>". $row['bavailable'] ."</td><td>
        <form method='post'>";
        if($key = array_search($row['serialno'], $arraynosiri) !== false) {
            $checkbox = "checked";
        }
        else{
            $checkbox = "";
        }

        echo "<script>
        var checkedCbs = $('.sBorrow:checked');
        if (checkedCbs.length === 3) {
          var uncheckedCbs = $('.sBorrow').not(':checked');
          $.each(uncheckedCbs, function(idx, cb) {
              $(cb).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
          });
        } else {
          var disabledCb = $('.sBorrow:disabled');
          disabledCb.attr('disabled', false);
          </script>";


        if($row['bavailable'] == "Available"){
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sBorrow' id='sBorrow' class='sBorrow' value='". $row['serialno'] ."' ".$checkbox.">
            </form></td></tr>";
            }
            else{
            echo "<input type='checkbox' name='sBorrow' id='sBorrow' class='sBorrow' value='". $row['serialno'] ."' ".$checkbox." style='color: grey;' disabled>
            </form></td></tr>";
        }


        $startrow++;
        //echo $row['education_level'];


}`
```

Comment: Perhaps your looking for something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806582/php-while-loop-variable-for-every-third-div

Comment: Well not actually. by 3rd checkbox, i meant that first user click any checkbox, then second one, then 3rd one. After the 3rd checkbox has been selected, i want all other checkbox disabled so that the user can't select it anymore. i know there are many cases like this. But i cant find one those checkbox are from looping. All of their checkbox has been assign manually and not from looping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you assign the same ID for all checkboxes?

When the checkbox is clicked, you have to count the number. When three checkboxes are checked, do the following to disable all checkboxes,

```
var checkboxes = $(".sBorrow").not(':checked');
$.each(checkboxes, function(idx, cb) {
    $(cb).attr("disabled", "disabled");
});
```

**Update**

The complete code looks like this. This is called every time a checkbox is being checked.

```
var checkedCbs = $('.sBorrow:checked');
if (checkedCbs.length === 3) {
  var uncheckedCbs = $('.sBorrow').not(':checked');
  $.each(uncheckedCbs, function(idx, cb) {
      $(cb).attr("disabled", "disabled");
  });
} else {
  var disabledCb = $('.sBorrow:disabled');
  disabledCb.attr("disabled", false);
}
```

Comment: i know i know..im not using that ID...just a habit putting name, id and class

Comment: I dont think its working. :(
i can do it with php. but as usual i need to refresh the page first :( i want it to disabled right after the user select all 3 checkbox and then can't select anymore.

Comment: Sorry, I've just tested it in JSFiddle. Now it should work.

Comment: cb was a DOM node. I need to wrap it with a $ because .attr is from jQuery. You can mark it as answered if you think it has helped.

Comment: Oh wait i found some bugs. or error in your code. Once it reach 3 its disabled. But when i uncheck some checkbox to reduce it to 2, the other checkbox still disables. In other words, i need to refresh once i check it to make it disabled

Comment: You need to enable it again using `$(cb).attr("disabled", false)`.

Comment: Already. but it seems i need to refreshed to see it in action. :(

Comment: can you check my code? i have edited it. i need to make sure im doing it right because the new updated code is not working

Comment: Your old code already done the job. but its not disabled until i refreshed it

Comment: Never mind. Your code was right. it just that i was putting it in wrong place. Thank you again :)